# React map function returning current object plus new properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you create an new array, with same objects but with extra properties. Sample below creates a new array with a subset of properties. But I try to do is create some new properties on existing objects. So result will be objects from accounts.data, with an extra property called test.

```
var options = accounts.data.map((o) => ({
  label: o.name,
  value: o.id,
  number: o.accountNumber,
  test: o.name+o.id
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const accounts = {
  data: [{
      name: 'Test 1',
      id: 0,
      number: "123456-10",
      otherProperty: "Hello World!"
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2',
      id: 1,
      number: "123456-11",
      otherProperty: "Hello World!!"
    },
  ]
};

const options = accounts.data.map((account) => ({ ...account,
  test: account.name + account.id
}));

console.log(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const accounts = {
  data: [
    {
      name: 'Test 1',
      id: 0,
      number: "123456-10",
      otherProperty: "Hello World!"
    },
    {
      name: 'Test 2',
      id: 1,
      number: "123456-11",
      otherProperty: "Hello World!!"
    },
  ]
}


var options = accounts.data.map((o) => Object.assign({},o, {
  label: o.name,
  value: o.id,
  number: o.accountNumber,
  test: o.name+o.id
})) 

console.log(options);
```